# Iterating over Numpy array, so that changes are reflected in the DataFrame (through reference)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, loops

what I want is to iterate over a Numpy array that is a reference to a pandas Dataframe.
The reason I want this is so that I can loop over the Numpy array, and the changes are reflected in the dataframe.

I use a Numpy array because I want to randomly select rows from the array (through `np.random.choice(firstNamesNumpyArray, size=50)`, change them by loop (e.g. all firstNames are 'x') and see the changes in the dataFrame (lines_df).

```
   with open('input_01.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
   lines_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=',', delimiter=None, encoding="utf-8", error_bad_lines=False, nrows=150,
                          header=0)

initialDFfirstNames = lines_df['firstNames']

firstNamesNumpyArray = initialDFfirstNames.to_numpy()

with np.nditer(firstNamesNumpyArray, op_flags=['readwrite'], flags=['refs_OK']) as it:
   for x in it:
       x[...] = 'x'
```

The initialDFfirstNames looks like this.

```
0         Boy
1      Stella
2      Elsina
3       Defne
4       Djura
       ...   
95       Coby
96    Michele
97     Jildau
98     Tamira
99       Fynn
Name: firstNames, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

I use np.nditer as the iterator but this gives the error:
`ValueError: Unexpected iterator global flag "refs_OK"`

But when I remove that flag I receive the error 
 `Iterator operand or requested dtype holds references, but the REFS_OK was not enabled.`

I know it holds references, and that is exactly what I want.
Anyone that has experience with this?

Kind regards, Daan

Comment: The flag is `refs_ok`, lowercase. As for what you're trying to do, I don't really follow why you need iteration

Comment: I don't think this will work as you intend.

Comment: The reason I want iteration is because for example all values in the array need to be ' ' an empty string. But this array i'm intending to use is only a part of the whole dataset. When I change the random splitted array, the change needs to be reflected in the initial DataFrame.

Comment: `nditer` may work if you call it right, but usually it isn't the optimal way to act on an array.  It doesn't improve iteration speed.  In this case the array is object dtype (since Pandas strings are stored as objects).  But can't you do a simple replacement like this directly in pandas?